# Is it possible to store user-generated-content on Game-Center and share among all users?

Tags: ios, game-center, user-generated-content

We are implementing a leveleditor for our game and want to enable submitting the user-generated levels. All other users of the game should be able to play these levels. Is it possible to store the levels in GameCenter or is the only way to achieve this to set up a dedicated server?

In case we have to go with our own server, are there any preconfigured services for this scenario? Something like dropbox, with a nice API instead of having to code everything ourselves from the ground up.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GameCenter does not currently have support for downloadable content.  You could peer-to-peer share small payloads of data between players using the matching API, but that's pretty clearly not what you want.

In thinking about other services, the first/easiest thing that comes to mind for me would be to use Amazon S3. It's super-simple, reasonably cheap, has good content distribution, availability, etc. (Sure beats running your own server, anyway.)

Comment: Thanks, I already thought so. Amazon seems a pretty good bet, thanks for the hint!